# Picking one row over another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID   Type   Value
A    Z01    10
A    Z09    20
B    Z01    30
C    Z01    40
D    Z09    50
E    Z10    60
```

For each ID I would like to retrieve a value. Ideally the value should come from the row with type Z01. However, if Z01 is not available I'll pick Z09 instead. If nothing is available I would like to select nothing.

The result would look like this:

```
Id   Type   Value
A    Z01    10
B    Z01    30
C    Z01    40
D    Z09    50
```

How can I accomplish this with T-SQL?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be in the original table. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
select *
from table t
where 1 = case 
              when t.type = 'Z01' 
                  then 1 
              when t.type = 'Z09' 
                    and not exists (select 1 from table where id = t.id and type = 'Z01')
                  then 1 
          else 0 
       end
```

An alternative, with using a more common approach is (re-writing the `CASE` expression):

```
select *
from table
where type = 'Z01'
    OR (type = 'Z09' and not exists (select 1 from table where id = t.id and type = 'Z01'))
```

An obvious `sargable` approach (which will make your query use the appropriate index on your table, if it exists) would be:

```
select *
from table
where type = `Z01`

union all
select *

from table
where type = `Z09`
    and not exists (select 1 from table where id = t.id and type = 'Z01')
```

And when I'm saying index I'm talking about a non-clustered index on the `type` column.

Comment: That's a complicated way to approach the problem.  A case expression doesn't belong in a `WHERE` clause. Use `AND`,  `OR` and parentheses instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Could be, but I guess they're both the same. And why doesn't a `CASE` expression belong in a `WHERE` clause? I'm curious if you have any examples for that.

Comment: This is also a [non-sargable](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/55535/sargable-queries-in-sql-server-with-examples/) query and will have very poor performance.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Based on what rules does my query become non-sargable? Unfortunately (for me), I fail to see why that is. Is it because of the `OR` ?

Comment: Hi, as you have shown with your second query, you can write any boolean expression in `WHERE` and it's simpler. There is no need for a construct that lets you create a value from a boolean expression in `WHERE`. `CASE` is made for the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses to make it possible to evaluate a boolean expression there.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu your original post with only the query that used the case statement requires case run for each row, meaning it's non-sargable.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Even so, there is almost no way of guaranteeing an index seek without knowing more about table structure. But, in terms of index utilisation, if there is an index on the `type` column then any approach will definitely use it (even if it turns out to be an index scan).

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY type) AS rn
FROM yourtable
WHERE type IN ('Z01', 'Z09'))
SELECT
    id, type, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when type = 'Z01' then 1
                                               when type = 'Z09' then 2
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I don't fully understand teh statement "if nothing is available, then choose nothing".  If, by this, you mean you want 'Z01', 'Z09' or nothing at all, then just do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by type) as seqnum
      from t
      where type in ('Z01', 'Z09')
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `where` clause does the filtering, and you can just order by the type alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Then try this

```
 Select distinct a.id, 
    coalesce(t1.type, t9.type) type,
    case when t1.type is not null 
         then t1.value else t9.value end value
 From table a 
    left join table t1 
       on t1.id = a.id 
          and t1.type = 'Z01'
    left join table t9 
       on t9.id = a.id 
          and t9.type = 'Z09'
  Where a.type in ('Z01', 'Z09')  -- < -- this last to eliminate row E
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select distinct
base.Id,
Coalesce(z01.Type, any.Type) Type,
Coalesce(z01.Value, any.Value)
from (select distinct id from [table]) base
left outer join [table] z01
    on z01.id = base.id
    and z01.Type = 'Z01'
left outer join [table] any
    on any.id = base.id
    and any.type != 'Z01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `WHERE` clause. Select only entries with Z01 and Z09. Then use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your rows and keep the best.

```
select id, type, value 
from
(
    select 
      id, type, value, 
      row_number() 
        over (partition by id order by case when type = 'Z01' then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    from mytable
    where type in ('Z01','Z09')
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```